# Repeating array with transformation

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

How can I repeat the following example sequence:

```
l = np.array([3,4,5,6,7])
```

Up to `n` times, doubling the values on each repetition. So for `n=3`:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28]
```

Is there a simple way avoiding loops with `numpy` perhaps?

Comment: Loops would be your best bet, is there a reason you cannot use loops?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`numpy.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) + [`numpy.ndarray.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html):

```
>>> a = np.array([3,4,5,6,7])                                                                                          
>>> n = 3                                                                                                              
>>> factors = 2**np.arange(n)                                                                                          
>>> np.outer(factors, a).ravel()                                                                                       
array([ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28])
```

Details:

```
>>> factors                                                                                                            
array([1, 2, 4])
>>> np.outer(factors, a)                                                                                               
array([[ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7], # 1*a
       [ 6,  8, 10, 12, 14], # 2*a
       [12, 16, 20, 24, 28]]) # 4*a
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use concatenate and list comprehension using powers of 2 as the multiplicative factor. Here `3` is the number of repetitions you need.

```
l = np.array([3,4,5,6,7])
final = np.concatenate([l*2**(i) for i in range(3)])
print (final)

array([ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
>>> (l * [[1], [2], [4]]).flatten()
array([ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28])
```

(Only works if you want multiples of the input.)

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

rows = np.tile(l, 3).reshape(-1, len(l)) * np.power(2, np.arange(3)).reshape(-1, 1)
print(rows.flatten())
```

**Output**

```
[ 3  4  5  6  7  6  8 10 12 14 12 16 20 24 28]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.power`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.power.html) with [`np.ndarray.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
A = np.array([3,4,5,6,7])

res = (A * np.power(2, np.arange(3))[:, None]).ravel()

print(res)

array([ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to loop over `n`, and concatenate a new list each time:

```
l = [3,4,5,6,7]
n = 3
new_l = []
for i in range(n):
    new_l += [j*2**i for j in l]
new_l = np.array(new_l)
```

**Output**

```
array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in pure python using list comprehensions:

```
l = [3,4,5,6,7]

n     = 3
mult  = [1 * 2**i for i in range(n)]
final = list([x*m for m in mult for x in l])
```